# Element margins ignored after floated element

Tags: css, css-float

I have a "cleared" `<hr>` tag with margins top and bottom. However, after two floated elements as columns, the top margin is ignored and the line sits right below the text.

CSS:

```
hr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border: 1px;
    background-color: #d3d7cf;
    color: #d3d7cf;
    clear: both;
    margin: 16px auto;
}
.column {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 16px;
    width: 200px
}
```

HTML:

```
<hr/>
<div class="column">asd<br />fgh</div>
<div class="column">asd</div>
<hr/>
```

I found out that I can wrap the columns in a div with `overflow: hidden`, but is there a solution where I don't need to add extra markup to the HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add margin-bottom: 16px to the "column" class.

Or add padding to the columns (obviously not if you're using borders on the column class).

Comment: One solution I just realised will work is setting the columns to `display:inline-block`. But I'm gonna go with your solution, since it's slightly more cross-browser.

Answer (score 3):

Add `float:left` to the `HR` style.

This should now make the `HR` play in the same flow as the floated `DIV`s and apply the top margin that you were missing in the first version of your CSS.